# Parabolic flight. h(t) vs 2 parametric equations.

Tags: calculus, parametric

Often you have something like:  $$h(t)=-16t^2+V_0t+C$$

I have little experience with parametric equations, but I have also seen parabolic functions represented this way:

$$x=x_0 + V_{0_x}*t$$

$$y=y_0 + V_{0_x}*t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

With a specific example, can someone talk about the connection between the two?
When is one format preferable?  Does it depend on what initial information you have available?  I also want to know how you convert one to the other.  etc.

Comment: How to convert: If you take the first parametric equation and solve for t, you get $t=\frac{x-x_0}{V_{0_x}}$, substitute this into the expression for y, you get y as a function of x.

Comment: Thanks, can you paste your solution as an answer so I can give you the points?

Comment: That x= equation does not take into account air resistance, etc.  The x velocity never decreases and is linear.

Comment: I'm not saying the equations will look good, but the method of substitution nevertheless works.

Comment: How did you notice my post on this old thread so quickly?  Do you have email alerts set?

Comment: I happened to be logged in just now, and there is an alert flashing at the top of the screen when someone writes a comment where I've previously commented. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense the first equation is also of 'parametric' form if you consider some parametric variable s, then you get

$$ t = s$$
$$ h = -16s^2 + V_0 t + C$$

Of course, this is a trivial parametrization.

You can convert from the latter to the former. Take the first parametric equation and solve for $t$, you get: $$t=x−x_0 V_0 x$$Substitute this into the expression for $y$, you get $y$ as a function of $x$.

Both forms have their uses, but I find it hard to provide a general "guideline" for when which is optimal, if that's even possible.